# CloneZilla syslinux.cfg works on yakkety but not on artful

Tags: clonezilla, syslinux

I installed CloneZilla 20180329 amd64, the artful alternative version and tried to automate some settings via the ocs_prerun variables. Specifically I want to set the locale and keyboard layout, the Wifi connection (if possible not the password) + dhcp and preseed the SMB server address and user (if possible not the password). This is my working /syslinux/sylinux.cfg from the CloeZilla yakkety version, that worked:

```
append initrd=/live/initrd.img boot=live union=overlay username=user hostname=yakkety config quiet components noswap edd=on nomodeset noeject locales=de_DE.UTF-8 keyboard-model=pc105 keyboard-layouts=de keyboard-variant=nodeadkeys ocs_prerun="wpa_passphrase MYWIFIAP MYWIFIPASSWORD > wpa.conf" ocs_prerun1="wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -cwpa.conf &" ocs_prerun2="sleep 3" ocs_prerun3="dhclient -v wlan0" ocs_prerun4="sleep 3" ocs_live_run="ocs-live-general" ocs_live_extra_param="" ocs_live_batch="no" vga=788 ip= net.ifnames=0 splash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=1
```

When I use this on the new CloneZilla version I have to still set up the keyboard and the WiFi + DHCP is not working either... What am I doing wrong? Also If anybody knowns how to preseed the SAMBA config I'd be really grateful. The CloneZilla option docs are a real mess...

Answer (score 0):

At least the keyboard settings seem to be working now with CloneZilla 20191024-eoan amd64 now. See [this](https://clonezilla.org/fine-print-live-doc.php?path=clonezilla-live/doc/99_Misc/00_live-boot-parameters.doc) on which config files to edit, depending on how the target system boots (CSM, UEFI, PXE etc.):

1. For Clonezilla live booting from CD on a MBR machine, isolinux is the boot loader. Therefore the config file is /syslinux/isolinux.cfg.
2. For Clonezilla live booting from USB flash drive on a MBR machine, syslinux is the boot loader. Therefore the config file is /syslinux/syslinux.cfg.
3. For Clonezilla live booting from PXE on a MBR machine, pxelinux is the boot loader. The config file is on the PXE server, and is configured by the system administrator. it could be something like /tftpboot/nbi_img/pxelinux.cfg/default, or different file.
4. For Clonezilla live booting from a uEFI machine, grub2 is used. Therefore the config file is /boot/grub/grub.cfg (Was /EFI/boot/grub.cfg).